# how to add bootstrap 3 to meteor1.1.0.2 projects

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, meteor

just a quick question. how do you add bootstrap 3 when you created a project on meteor 1.1.0.2. im using a windows os version. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the Twitter Bootstrap [package](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) to your Meteor app easily with one command:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

This will add all javascript plugins and styles automatically to your application.

Comment: is this will automatically add to bootstrap 3.5? how can i know if i already added bootstrap 3.5?

Comment: @hilarion: You'll know because you will see Bootstrap's familiar CSS selectors in the compiled css. Also check your `packages` file, you should see it named there.

Comment: yeah your right. it works. when i added meteor add twbs:bootstrap, it says bootstrap added, version 3.3.5. cool. thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want default Bootstrap and all of its components, you can simply add it to your app from the command line by running [`meteor add twbs:bootstrap`](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap).

If you need to configure the different variables and components that are included, you can use the `nemo64:bootstrap` package instead. See the directions for how to configure it on the [Atmosphere page](https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap).